# Since support for FormData.delete() is low, what's the alternative for this method or how to achieve the same behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website uses `FormData.delete()` to exclude certain form fields from the form before sending the data to the server. However, it turns out `FormData.delete()` isn't supported in lots of browsers, even Safari. As a result, I have to switch the method to something else, or achieve the behaviour in a certain way.

This is the current code:

```
let formData = new FormData(this)
formData.delete('files[]')
```

The point is to remove the `files[]` from the `FormData`. Right now what I can think of the alternative way to get the same result is to manually add each form field to `FormData` instead. But I certainly hope for a better method. Any input?

Comment: hmm... could you move the file fields out of the form before calling new FormData?

Answer (score 1):

code from guest271314 doesn't work in IE and Edge (caused by for (let prop of fd) {), i did it like this

```
var origData = new FormData(form);

var newData    = new FormData();
var exclude    = "files[]";
var inputs     = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
var inputsList = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs);

inputsList.forEach(
    function (i) {
        if (i.name !== exclude) {
            newData.append(i.name, i.value);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `FormData` object and `.append()` selected elements to a new `FormData` object

```js
var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);

var data = new FormData();

var not = "files[]";

for (let prop of fd) {
  console.log(prop[0], prop[1]);
  if (prop[0] !== not) {
    data.append(prop[0], prop[1]);
  }
 
}

for (let prop of data) {
  console.log(prop[0], prop[1]);
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="file" name="files[]">
<input type="text" name="text" value="123">
</form>
```

Comment: Not working in Edge. Got an error `Object doesn't support property or method 'Symbol.iterator'`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and gone through several forums but did not find proper solution for it.

formData.delete is not supported in IE/Edge/Safari (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete)

Only solution to this at present is to manually add the key/value in newly created formData and post that to server.

```
//This is your actual form data
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("files[]","TestFile");
formdata.append('Key1', "value1");
formdata.append('Key2', "value2");
formdata.append('Key3', "value3");

//This is the new form data
var Newformdata = new FormData();

//Adding the rest of the values which you want to preseve in Newformdata 
Newformdata.append('Key1', "value1");
Newformdata.append('Key2', "value2");
Newformdata.append('Key3', "value3");
```